# why my stylesheet is not applying my style which I code newly even when it is included properly in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am making wordpress design and have included it using wp_register_style and wp_enqueue_style functions. The codes in function.php are as bellow:

```
function themeSetup (){

    wp_register_style( 'prostyle', get_template_directory_uri() .'/common/prostyle.css', array(), null, 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'prostyle' );

    wp_register_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), null, 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style' );

    wp_register_script( 'JqueryCDN', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js', '', null, false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'JqueryCDN' );

    wp_register_script( 'proscript', get_template_directory_uri() .'/common/proscript.js', '', null, false, false );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'proscript' );


}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'themeSetup');
```

Main Problem: My previously written css is working on the site but each new css rule in same file which is included are neither showing on browser nor it is applying to elements.

Plz, kindly tell me what I am missing in such codes. If there is anywhere wrong in wp_register_script or style function please tell me.

Comment: Refresh the browser cache (CTRL+F5) Probably the css file is not being noticed as changed so is not being re-downloaded by the browser

Comment: Yes, it worked but I don't understand why it is not occured on simple click? Is it because of wordpress functions? and it has any solution?

Comment: This is not a WP issue its a general caching issue

Comment: Thanks for solution @riggs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1 : Always use Private window or incognito mode in case of chrome.

Step 2 : disable your cache plugin if any.

Step 3:  attach version in your style that force server to use newer version.

Step 4: Cloud flare is not taking your css as a newer version.

Comment: Vasim, your suggestion is looks cool but I am unaware to do step 3 so kindly explain it for me and if possible tell me solution to avoide step 4 problem.

Comment: gogle stylesheet versioning in wp.style.css?ver=1.0

Comment: I have use w3tc in wordpress and attach cloudflare so when clear from w3tc it automatically refresh cloudflare also

Comment: Thanks for your help.